# Getting run time error in Highmaps in ionic

Tags: highcharts

1. Add Plugin 'angular2-highcharts'
2. add code for highmaps

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hc4s.png)

Comment: Well the error URL says "Rendering div not found", so that should probably be the issue. Not enough info to say much more than that from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use this code

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      chart: {
        map: 'custom/europe',
        spacingBottom: 20
      },

    title: {
       text: 'Europe time zones'
     },

    legend: {
       enabled: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
      map: {
        allAreas: false,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#FFFFFF',
          style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
          },
      // Only show dataLabels for areas with high label rank
       format: null,
       formatter: function () {
        if (this.point.properties && this.point.properties.labelrank.toString() < 5) {
            return this.point.properties['iso-a2'];
        }
    }
        },
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '',
          pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
      }
      }
    },


    })
    }
```

Comment: Ionic is a framework based on Angular so perhaps it will be a better idea to use Highcharts official wrapper `highcharts-angular`. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular. Here you can find an online example of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4. I hope it will help you.